# Iron router splash page "Organize your meteor application" flashing up - how to change it?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

On my Meteror cordova mobile app, first time users see the Iron Router splash page "Organize your meteor application" flashing up the first time they open it app.

It gives a terrible impression, even if it only flashes for a few seconds. I understand that bits and pieces of the app are still loading, so there's a short time when this is open.

How to customise this page so it's less ugly? A blank page is fine to be honest.

Comment: Maybe try to add something like [this control structure inside your action](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#the-subscriptions-option).

Comment: I'm already using the subscription option for my 'home' route, and do get a loading spinner too. But somehow... Iron Router's splash page appears before my 'home' route gets loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was the mdg:reload-on-resume package that was causing this. Try disabling that if you're using it.

Comment: had a look, that package is not on my versions so I guess it's not one of my dependencies :/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the location of the iron router package in your .packages file, it could be getting loaded quite a bit sooner than your route, which is usually loaded in application code (after all the packages are loaded).

I've had the same problem as you and have created a package that just creates my homepage route. Then I load my homepage route package right after iron:router in the .packages file and that eliminates the gap between iron router loading and your first route being created. Don't forget to remove the route from your application code after moving it into the package so you don't have a duplicate route being created.